# "He is just not that into me": lacking predicate?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-structure

> He is just not that into me.

I don't know what meaning of this sentence. As I see, this is a wrong sentence due to lacking predicate?

Comment: Please wait a day or two before accepting an answer. [This meta question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700) explains why this is usually wise.

Comment: The subject is _he_ and the predicate is the verb phrase _is just not that into me._

Comment: It's highly idiomatic and informal, of course. _Just not that into me_ is subjective predicative complement of "be". It ascribes the property of _not being into me_ to the subject "he", in much the same way that an adjective phrase would, cf. _He is just not very interested in me._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a proper sentence: the predicate complement of *BE* is a preposition phrase, just like an ordinary locative preposition phrase:

> He is *in the corner*.
>   This problem is not *over my head*.

*Into me* here has the idiomatic meaning *interested in, engaged in, excited by*; for instance

> He is into role-playing games = *He is interested in roleplaying games*

And *that* is used idiomatically here as a measure adverb meaning approximately "to that degree" or "to the desired/needed degree".

So "He is just not that into me" may be paraphrased

> He is not as interested in me as I would like.

Comment: I don't know how to get those `as interested in` still when I face another sentence..Do you have another similar example?

Comment: I'll add that to "be into someone" specifically has a romantic context, so "He is just not that into me" can be rewritten as "He is just not **attracted to/in love with** me."

Comment: @yode "not that into me" = "not interested in me to the desired degree" = "not as interested in me as I would like". In another context the exact meaning might be somewhat different: "He's not that into role-playing games" might mean "He's not so interested in role-playing games as you say" or "He's not so interested in role-playing games that I would invite him to play with us".

Comment: @StoneyB Well,I have to say we have a better head to polishing those omitted part. :)

Comment: @StoneyB - I think you're comment describes the difference between "being into someone" and "being into something". When it's into some*one*, that's usually alluding to a romantic interest; but when it's into some*thing*, then it simply means enjoys in some capacity.

Comment: @J.R. W e l l ... I used "interested" to be more generalizable. I like Liz Warren, but I'm not that into Bernie.

Comment: Stoney - I thought of a few counterexamples as well, but I knew that yours would be better than mine. I was right. :-) I agree that "into someone" does have some secondary meanings, but I also think @Alexander made a good point about it often alluding to romance.